# highcharts marker: {radius: 10} on individual data points makes certain data points disappear?

Tags: highcharts

This works just fine:

```
data: [{x:-90,y:-30,name:'1: blah blah'}]
```

However I want to change the radius of individual data points based on the amount of votes an item receives, so i do this:

```
data: [{x:-90,y:-30,name:'1: blah blah',marker:{radius: 5}}]
```

and the data point disappears?  Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: odd behavior.  It appears to relate to the negative y value - if you try it with positive y values, it works fine.  Negative y value, it disappears...

Comment: Good call. I can confirm that it's only not working on negative y values.

Comment: Have you tried to use bubble chart? http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/g8JcL/

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't necessarily solving the problem, but it is a work around.

I changed my y values to all be positive numbers, so instead of going -50 to 50, i'm going 0 to 100 and I will ultimately get the effect on the chart that I desire.